# Output raw image from Imagick image in PHP

Tags: php, stdout, imagick

I'm using Imagick lib to do some modifications to original image. Then I'd like to output it directly to browser without saving. Is there a way to do that?

I tried to use `Imagick::writeImage('STDOUT')` (empty output) and 'php://stdout' with error "Unable to write to file".

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You just need to echo your imagick object:

```
$img = new Imagick($file);
header('Content-Type: image/'.$img->getImageFormat());
echo $img;
```

Comment: As illustrated in example #1: http://es2.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php

Comment: I'd go with `header('Content-Type: image/'.$img->getImageFormat());` -- but otherwise very nice :)

Comment: If, for some reason, you do not want to echo image, you can get its content by calling `$img->__toString()`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using HHVM it'll throw a fatal exception if you just try and echo the Imagick object so you'll need to call getimageblob();

```
$imagick = new Imagick('my-image.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/' . $imagick->getImageFormat());
echo $imagick->getimageblob();
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what Schneck meant is:

```
header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
$fp = fopen('php://stdout', 'w+');
$image->writeImageFile($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

This *may* cause problems, especially in multipage files, so you should probably use:

```
ob_start();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
$image->writeimagefile($fp); // or writeImagesFile for multipage PDF
fclose($fp);
$out = ob_get_clean();
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($out));
echo $out;
```

This is tested and working.

I realize this is an old question. The reason I'm posting this is that if you want to write a multipage PDF, this is the solution, as Nabab's solution only works for single images.

You can also use (PHP 5.1.0+):

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
$image->writeimagesfile($fp);
rewind($fp);
$out = stream_get_contents($fp);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($out));
fclose($fp);
echo $out;
```

This way seems to be faster if your PHP version supports it.

Before you downvote, the reason I added this as an answer and not a comment is I don't have sufficient reputation to comment. Hope that is alright. Just wanted to get this out there in case anyone needed it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `Imagick::writeImageFile("php://stdout")` (untested)?