# Convert image format PNG to JPEG without saving to disk - PHP

Tags: php, gdlib

- I am taking a PNG image from a url as below.
- I want to convert the PNG image to JPEG without saving disk with PHP.
- Finally I want to assign JPEG image to $content_jpg variable.

  ```
   $url = 'http://www.example.com/image.png';
   $content_png = file_get_contents($url);

   $content_jpg=;
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert the image?' If you want to edit the image, you don't need to save the image, just output it. See: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: I am doing this in Oxwall. After converting I will save jpg image to system generated location. But I want know the possibility of converting png image content($content_png) to jpg without writing to disk.This is possible whit C# as a tutorial I found.

Comment: @Josh, I want to change the format of image from PNG to JPEG. That is what I want to mean by convert the image' and not the edit image. Thanks

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, I will output image to browser. Please let us know if you have any better solution than what we found. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [gd library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) for this. Here's an example which will take a png image and output a jpeg one. If the image is transparent, the transparency will be rendered as white instead.

```
<?php

$file = "myimage.png";

$image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$quality = 50;
imagejpeg($bg);
imagedestroy($bg);

?>
```

Comment: The function imagecreatefrompng can accept urls too. So I have passed url to function instead a file. This code work as expected and it out put JPEG file to browser. Thank you very much Josh.

Answer (score 5):

Simplified answer is,

```
// PNG image url
$url = 'http://www.example.com/image.png';

// Create image from web image url
$image = imagecreatefrompng($url);

// Start output buffer
ob_start(); 

// Convert image
imagejpeg($image, NULL,100);
imagedestroy($image);

// Assign JPEG image content from output buffer
$content_jpg = ob_get_clean();
```